# Express Js write raw http2 headers to the res object socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http2

I need to get a raw socket after a request on specific url on my site, i have logic like this, im running http2 server using spdy:

bin.js:

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('http2-nodejs-test:server');
const spdy = require('spdy');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '443');
app.set('port', port);

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
    cert:  fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem'),
    ca : fs.readFileSync('chain.pem'),
    spdy: {
        protocols: [ 'h2'],
        plain: false
    }
}
spdy.createServer(options, app).listen(port);
```

In my app.js there is routing logic:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');


var app = express();



// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/api/flow', function(req, res){

});
```

in

```
app.get('/api/flow', function(req, res){

});
```

I tried to take response socket, and send headers manually, replying with code 200, but connection hangs up for some reason:

```
app.get('/api/flow',function(req, res){

    var val = req.spdyStream.id;

    var data = new Buffer ([0x00, 0x00, 0x02,  0x1, 0x5]); // HTTP2 headers frame
    var stream_id = new Buffer(4); 
    stream_id.writeUInt32BE(val, 0, noAssert=false);  // add stream id to HTTP2 header
    var payload = new Buffer([0x88,0x87]);           // write payload
    data = Buffer.concat([data, stream_id, payload]);

    var sock = res.connection;
    sock.write(data,'binary');
});
```

What i do here is i write the HEADERS http2 frame manually in the response socket, `var payload = new Buffer([0x88,0x87]);`  are indexes inside static http2 headers table:

```
0x88 = :status: 200
0x87 = :scheme: https
```

That what i expect to see the browser will be receiving, but it doesnt, it hangs up, and  then i get connection timeout. Maybe i need the access to the SSL socket? Or actual SPDY stream? Also i cannot just use `res.end()` after this write, because it will add headers manually, that i don't want to be added. I need to send custom payload, so `res.write` etc doesn't suit me

**UPDATE**

Here is what i get in wireshark:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzBrX.png)

As you can see, my http2 header, got wrapped around in the DATA payload for some reason:

```
00 00 0b 00 00 00 00 00 15 00 00 02 01 05 00 00
00 15 88 87
```

The frame that i assume i have written starts with `00 00 02` why does this happens?

**UPDATE2**

I have removed all middleware, i left with only this:

```
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I still get my headers frame wrapped inside DATA for some reason

Comment: Even though the browser hangs up, can you check if data is being sent? I would suggest to use Wireshark or tcpdump for this kind of check.

Comment: It would probably be better if you made your question about the actual overall problem you're having.  As it is now, you're asking about issues with one solution path (getting access to the RAW socket) which is probably not really the right way to solve things.

Comment: @lilezek i updated my post and attached screen

Comment: @jfriend00 updated post title

Comment: @jfriend00 i know its not the right way, incorrect way etc, that is the purpose of this web application, it meant to be used for pentesting on some http2 clients, that's why i want to do that, it's not official website/landing and never would be

Comment: @BratecKrolik you have a lot of middlewares. They may be writing these bytes you see at the beginning.

Comment: @lilezek updated my main post

Comment: @lilezek i assume that spdy does something here, is there a way i can get access to the actual SSL socket from the `res` object? It seems that the `res.connection` is handled by `spdy`